# Problem to set two network interface on a virtual ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: server, virt-manager

I have to assign to VM (ubuntu 14.04, installed on virtual environment using virt-manager).
On virt-manager I've already created 2 vnetwork like that

[image]

this is the VM with the 2 vnet assigned

[image]

while the interface file is configured in this way

**`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`**

```
# The PUBLIC first network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 1.1.1.254
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 1.1.1.0
        broadcast 1.1.1.255
        gateway 1.1.1.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1
# The PRIVATE second network interface
auto eth1
iface eth0 inet static
        address 1.1.10.254
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 1.1.10.0
        broadcast 1.1.10.255
        gateway 1.1.10.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 1.1.10.1
```

while the command ifconfig -a shown all the interface

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:36:50:3d  
          inet addr:1.1.1.254  Bcast:1.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe36:503d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:765 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:716 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:240028 (240.0 KB)  TX bytes:242849 (242.8 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:9c:81:b5  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:22278 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22278 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:7130945 (7.1 MB)  TX bytes:7130945 (7.1 MB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:3c:72:75:26:f8  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I've also run lshw -c network,and the interface result in disable

```
  *-network:0             
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Virtio network device
       vendor: Red Hat, Inc
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 00
       serial: 52:54:00:36:50:3d
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=virtio_net driverversion=1.0.0 ip=1.1.1.254 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
       resources: irq:11 ioport:c020(size=32) memory:fc096000-fc096fff memory:fc000000-fc03ffff
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Virtio network device
       vendor: Red Hat, Inc
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 00
       serial: 52:54:00:9c:81:b5
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=virtio_net driverversion=1.0.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:11 ioport:c040(size=32) memory:fc097000-fc097fff memory:fc040000-fc07ffff
```

why does the eth1 interface not receive the IP address via file while manual yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ops, I'm so inattentive....this has been the error

```
auto eth1
iface eth0 inet static
```

I wrong the iface